# Проверка почты, которая привязана к Epic Games аккаунту

Tags: api

Допустим, у меня есть почта `example@example.com`. Можно как-нибудь узнать существует ли аккаунт к которому привязана эта почта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь воспользоваться официальным [api EGS](https://dev.epicgames.com/docs/epic-account-services/auth/auth-interface)

Или же можно сделать через костыли. Для этого нужен Selenium. Погугли сам или вот [статья](https://www.awesomeandrew.ru/2019/07/23/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-selenium-%D0%B2-python/) для ознакомления. Вот [страница](https://www.epicgames.com/id/login/forgot-password) для восстановления пароля через почту EGS. Если почта существует перекинет на след страницу, а если нет - покажет ошибку на этой же. Можно сравнить url после отправки формы. Не знаю, будет ли ругаться на капчу, смотри по ходу дела. Изучи [страницу восстановления пароля](https://www.epicgames.com/id/login/forgot-password) веб инспектором, посмотри какие запросы отправляет, может чего нароешь интересного

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Обязательно проверю, если всё получиться отмечу принятым.